how to change "show applications" icon in ubuntu 24.04
I want to change the "view-app-grid-symbolic.svg" into an Ubuntu icon, I have tried replacing it using the Ubuntu icon svg I downloaded online, but the grid disappeared completely.

perhaps this was the way to do it. If your system is now bricked, you may need to re-install or follow the guide using a live USB

The icon comes with the theme you use. Reinstalling your theme thus should restore the icon.
If you directly manipulated the files installed by the default theme, then try reinstalling that theme:
sudo apt install --reinstall yaru-theme-icon

Next time, if you want to override a system icon, place a file with the same name in either ~/.local/share/icons or ~/.icons (you do not need to be root and the change applies only to your account) or in /usr/local/share/icons if the change is to affect all users. This way, you do not mess with the files installed through the package manager, and any changes made by the package manager will not override your custom changes.
